# Problema de contexto javascript en angular

Tags: javascript, angular

- Tengo un componente `A` y un componente `B`
- En mi componente `A` hago una instancia de mi componente `B`

Html del componente A

```
<b [onPress]="onPressAComponent"></b>
```

En el `.ts` de mi componente `A`, exactamente en el metodo `onPressAComponent`, me trae el contexto de del componente `B` en lugar del componente `A`

Cuando hago `console.log(this)`, claramente se ve el contexto del componente `B`

yo en react, lo resolviera asi:

```
<b [onPress]="e => onPressAComponent(e)"></b>
```

Pero me da un error..

¿Como consigo obtener el contexto del propio componente cuando utilizo un método como callback?

EDITO:

`.ts` componente B

```
export class DropdownSelectComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() title
  @Input() name
  @Input() onPress
  @Input() data

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onClick(index){
    this.onPress(index)
    this.name = this.data[index].name
  }

}
```

`.ts` componente A (donde tengo el problema)

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  ...

  onPressEnvironment( index ){
    console.log( this )
    // devuelve: DropdownSelectComponent {title: "Entorno", name: "Selecciona", onPress: ƒ, data: Array(2)}
    // deberia devolver: HomeComponent {...}

  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: No es un error!! es el contexto del componente, es decir, quiero usar this, del componente A, pero me trae como si estuviera haciendo this del componente B, y el metodo esta en el componente A

Comment: ahi coloque el codigo por si te sirve de algo..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que al trabajar con angular necesitar utilizar un `EventEmiiter` desde el componente `B` para que `A` lo pueda instanciar. Esto se hace de manera **asincrona** de forma que tienes que esperar a que el `EventEmitter` se lanze. Necesitas un `@Output() miVariable = new EventEmitter<B>()` y lanzarlo en el `ngOnInit(){}`. Lo que estás obteniendo no es la instancia del componente, es el evento que está desencadenando `e`

Esta puede ser una forma de resolver el problema:

[Stack Blitz de ejemplo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n1yyim)

Otra forma de resolverlo es con un servicio. De esta manera no obtienes componentes únicos y puedes tener problemas al tratar de utilizar varias veces un mismo componente que depende de un servicio inyectado (por que este es el mismo para todos y por esta razón comparte los datos )

Comment: Me ha funcionado con el EventEmitter, a parte que tenia un error de sintaxsis, tenia [onPress] ="metodo" y es (onPress) ="metodo($event)"

Answer (score 1):

La solución es cambiar la declaración en la plantilla, en lugar de *declarar* el método

```
[onPress]="metodo"
```

Has de *usar* el método :

```
[onPress] ="metodo($event)"
```

Comment: Tanto que me esforcé en mi respuesta. `$event` Es el componente en sí?  Es algo muy interesante.

Comment: No, es el evento en sí. Es igual que cuando usas `addEventListener('press', event =>...) `

Comment: Estaba malinterpretando la pregunta. Crei que queria comunicar dos componentes.

Comment: @Angel porque eliminaste tu respuesta la estaba leyendo!! creo que por ahi iba la cosa...

Comment: @Franklin'jGil'z Ok, ya volvió,